# How can I fix object error for MVC dropdownlistfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Please help with some guidance. I am not sure where I am going wrong here.

My class

```
 public class UploadExpressClients
    {
        [Display(Name = "Clients")]
        public string UEclient { get; set; }
        public string clientdesc { get; set; }
        public List<UploadExpressClients> GetUploadExpressClients { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult UploadExpressAccess()
        {
            ackmanagerEntities db = new ackmanagerEntities();
            UploadExpressClients objClients = new UploadExpressClients();
            objClients.GetUploadExpressClients = db.profiles.Select(x => new UploadExpressClients { clientdesc = x.FileDesc, UEclient = x.Client }).ToList();

                return View(new UploadExpressClients());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadExpressAccess(UploadExpressClients objClients)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("UploadExpressAccess");
        }
```

And my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.clientdesc,
    Model.GetUploadExpressClients.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text= x.UEclient, Value = x.clientdesc.ToString()}),
    new { @class = "form-Control chosen-select" })

    <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" />

 }
```

Comment: This: `return View(new UploadExpressClients());` should be this: `return View(objClients);`

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks. I made the change but still getting error.

Comment: You need to debug. Is your objClients populated before it hits the view?

Comment: @SteveGreene I dont think thats happening after digging. When I put a break point at objClients, It never hits it and I get the error.

Comment: You should post the failing line. Would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try--

**Model:**

```
   public class UploadExpressClients
{
    [Display(Name = "Clients")]
    public string UEclient { get; set; }
    public string clientdesc { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DropDownOptionList { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UploadExpressAccess()
    {

        UploadExpressClients objClients = new UploadExpressClients();

        @using(var db = new ackmanagerEntities()){
         objClients.DropDownOptionList = db.profiles
         .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.FileDesc.ToString(), Text = x.Client })
         .ToList();
        }

        return View(objClients);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadExpressAccess(UploadExpressClients objClients)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("UploadExpressAccess");
    }
```

**View:**

```
 @using UploadExpressClients

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.clientdesc,Model.DropDownOptionList,"--Select--",new { 
 @class = "form-Control chosen-select" })

    <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" />

 }
```

Comment: This does not work. Errors all over the place. But thank you